# count down for comments edit

Tags: feature-request, comments

OK, I have 5 minutes for re-editing my comment.

But if I start to correct/extend it **in time** but I get an error message after hitting enter, about comments can edit within 5 minutes, that's not good.

Maybe a hurry message/ count down next to character counter would be useful.

I mean something like this:
[image]

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens. 

You should not use it to write up long texts. You can edit them to fix typos and stuff, but that's it.

Comment: You can see the time elapsed since you posted the comment (after your user name, before the `edit` link) and it's even updated dynamically now. Are you really sure you need more?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but when I re-edit it I cant see

Comment: I just edited my comment and I still can see the elapsed time. What do you mean?

Comment: We don't need a hurry message. We need a "calm down and think before you post" message at most.

Comment: I feel if implemented the timer should bleep menacingly and have James Bond Villain style "1 minute and counting" narrations.

Comment: If out-of-time, just copy the content, delete the comment you can no longer change, and re-add it.

Comment: The the order will change if anyone else posts in that time

Comment: @user65130 1) So? 2) this is at the dog-end of the the five-minutes grace for editing a comment. If you feel that so much may have happened to make it so complicated to follow the comments, then don't delete. It was a suggestion of something to try when a comment can no longer be edited. It is not an order, or suggested as a panacea for all situations. On the stuff I see, it would work 99,999 times out of 10,000 (if there ever get to be anywhere near 10,000).

Comment: @Bart Now, there's a thought... self-destructing comments!

Comment: @BillWoodger That's fitting an awful lot into 10,000, a real squeeze indeed.